# GCP - when trying to change the default location when loading file from cloud stroage to bigquery using php

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a dataset lets name it dataset1, in asia-northeast1 location. When I try to load file from storage which is in the same location, i'm getting the error
Dtaset Not Found:Please verify that the dataset exists and the correct location was used for the job.
Note(Sure that the dataset is exists and the region of dataset and storage file which i'm trying to load are in same region).
This is the library function which i'm using to load file to big query from storage.

```
    function loadFileToBigQuery($uri_array, $schema_array, $dataset, $table_name) 
{
    $loadConfig = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfigurationLoad();
    $loadConfig->setSchema($this->createSchema($schema_array));
    $loadConfig->setSourceUris($uri_array);
    $loadConfig->setDestinationTable($this->createDestinationTable($dataset, $table_name));
    $loadConfig->setCreateDisposition("CREATE_IF_NEEDED");
    $loadConfig->setWriteDisposition("WRITE_APPEND");
    $loadConfig->sourceFormat = 'CSV';
    $config = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfiguration();
    $config->setDryRun(false);
    $config->setLoad($loadConfig);
    $job = new Google_Service_Bigquery_Job();
    $job->setConfiguration($config);
    // this may throw exception: Google_Service_Exception
    $job = $this->service->jobs->insert($this->project_id, $job);

    return $job;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you setting a location on the `$job` resource?

Comment: How are you authenticating each transaction? It might be that the DatasetNotFound error is related to not being properly authenticated.

I also notice that your code doesn't use the [BigQuery client library for PHP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bigquery-load-table-gcs-csv-create-php). Is there any restriction that prevents you from using the client library as described in the docs?